# How I can get web Url & fill it in Matlab

Tags: html, matlab

I have web page that contain selectors such as instruments, periods, starting date & end date with submit button.
I hope to get various csv files.
In which way I can automate it in MATLAB environment.
the web page is:
https://www.fibogroup.com/clients/platforms/quotes-archive/

my request is about get instruments, periods, starting date & end date with submit button in Matlab code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want Matlab's `webread`, `webwrite`, and `websave` functions. They're how you interact with web sites and web services in Matlab code.

Do "View Source" on that web site in your browser to figure out how it's constructing its URLs. Or contact them to see if it's documented.